# rails and bootstrap - selectively/randomly works

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner coder and am trying to integrate my css into my app.  Using Rails 4 + Bootstrap 3.

1. I wrote out the html + css for the front-end of my app prior and it all worked fabulously.  I moved everything to my folder and edited my V + C accordingly.
2. I have installed the bootstrap-sass gem successfully.  Have updated my assets application and js.  I have a .scss file importing bootstrap and my Google fonts.
3. Bootstrap, Bootstrap js, and Google fonts are working selectively/randomly on certain pages, but not fully on a page or they just don't work at all or they are there but all messed up now.  (ex. modal not working on one page, but js element on another page works)  I am trying to call the css files from where they are locally stored.

My questions:
1.  Is there something I would need to edit to integrate the two in addition to the above?
2.  Do I have to transition my css into another file?
3.  If there is no easy way to fix this, should I just start over with my css?

Would appreciate any tips.  Thanks!

Comment: In your comment you mentioned your css is being overridden to check it you can try removing your required css files inside application.css.scss and check your pages and see if there is any faulty css file

Comment: Hi - already tried that and didn't work.

Comment: how did you install bootstrap in your app? can you post your gem file and application.css files

Comment: thanks for the help.  I just rewrote everything in sass in the same file and it worked.

Comment: Glad you got it working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be to check your sources under the inspector, to make the that the css and javascript are both being required. Also check the console for whether there are any javascript errors.

Assuming you are on google chrome, and on a mac, that would be `cmd+alt+i`, and `ctrl+alt+i` on windows.

You can also check which files are being included through checking page source by right clicking most parts of the page.

If they are being required and styles are not being applied then something else is probably getting in the way( i.e. bootstrap javascript files are being required twice, css is being overwritten because of load order, etc)

Comment: thanks for the tip Sherwyn, I have already tried using the inspector to see which files are loading but I couldn't find anything.  I suspect that something is overriding my stylesheets, but not sure which file - it seems like the css defaults to bootstrap one some pages and no css on others.

Comment: The fastest fix would be to manually add the script tag into the html and require the necessary files. If you placed the require helper in your application.html, and you do in fact render a layout from the controller,and you required the necessary file via sprockets in your application.js and application.css, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, will play around with it a bit more.